# Problem in valuation theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Find $\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}$, such that $v_2(\alpha-1/3)\ge 2$, $v_3(\alpha-1/2)\ge 3$ and $|\alpha-1|_\infty<1/2$, where $v_p$ is the $p$-adic exponential valuation and $|\cdot|_\infty$ is the usual absolute value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: @Alon Amit, thanks for the comment. I have tried to do some 3-adic and 2-adic expansion for 1/2 and 1/3, respctively, then I may find α by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. But I am confused with the expansions, since what I have got is quite different from what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two conditions are equivalent to $v_2(3\alpha-1)\ge2$ and $v_3(2\alpha-1)\ge3$. That is,

$$3\alpha-1\equiv 0 \mod 2^2\Bbb Z \qquad and \qquad 2\alpha-1 \equiv 0 \mod 3^3\Bbb Z.$$

Rewriting each side (note $2^{-1}\equiv 14\mod 27$), we obtain

$$\begin{cases} \alpha\equiv -1 \mod 4 \\ \alpha \equiv  14 \mod 27. \end{cases}$$

By [CRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) we have $\alpha=95 \mod 108$. We need $|p/q-1|_\infty <1/2$ while $pq^{-1} \equiv 95 ~(108)$. The two nontrivial factors of $95$ are $5$ and $19$; we have $5^{-1}\equiv 65$ and $19^{-1}\equiv 91 \mod 108$. The latter is close to $5+108=113$ in the $|\cdot|_\infty$ metric, so we check that $|113/91-1|_\infty<1/2$ indeed holds.

This gives $\alpha=113/91$ as one solution.

Comment: @Qiang: If you want to do it by hand it'd be the [extendend Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). Otherwise cheat and consult google for an online applet. :)

Comment: Anon, a thousand thanks for your answer! I want to know if there some tricks in solving the equation such as $19x\equiv1 \mod 108$? P.S. I thought about the weak approximation theorem later on today, feeling the problem would be solved by the constructive proof. But I didn't really do it after I read your answer. It's a really great answer!

Comment: Anon, I got it. Thanks. It seems that your solution is actually $\alpha=113/91$. I'm sorry I cannot @you on this computer.

Comment: @Qiang: Oops, typo. Fixed, thanks. Don't worry, comments on a person's answer always ping that person, so `@anon` would be redundant here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $\alpha = \frac{a}{b}$ then

$\alpha-\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2a-b}{2b}$

$\alpha-\frac{1}{3} = \frac{3a-b}{3b}$

You need to make the first fraction divisible by a high power of 3, and the second divisible by a high power of 2. It's easiest to make $b$ relatively prime to 6 so you don't have to worry about the denominators. Pick such a $b$. Can you find an $a$ such that $2a-b$ is divisible by 27? Can you find an $a$ that makes $3a-b$ divisible by 4? Can you find an $a$ that does both? Finally, can you make $a$ close enough to $b$ so that $\frac{a}{b}$ is not too far from 1?

Comment: Alon, thanks for your hint! I will try that. Later on today, I found that the weak approximation theorem will be useful here.